# Calling phone number cuts first zero

Tags: java, android, xml, phone-call

Here is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private long sTime = 0L;
    private Handler myHandler = new Handler();
    private long wait2 = 1000000000;
    private int telnum2;`

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Button butt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butt);
        Button buttstop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttstop);
        if (butt != null) {
            butt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    EditText wait = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                    wait2 = Integer.parseInt(wait.getText().toString()) * 1000;
                    EditText telnum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
                    telnum2 = Integer.parseInt(telnum.getText().toString());
                    sTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                    myHandler.removeCallbacks(AutoCaller);
                    myHandler.postDelayed(AutoCaller, wait2);

                }
            });
        }
        buttstop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myHandler.removeCallbacks(AutoCaller);
            }
        });
    }

    private Runnable AutoCaller = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final long start = sTime;
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + telnum2)));
            myHandler.postDelayed(this, wait2);
        }
    };
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        myHandler.removeCallbacks(AutoCaller);
        super.onPause();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        myHandler.postDelayed(AutoCaller, wait2);
    }}
```

layout_main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

It creates 2 EditText and 2 Buttons.
I type number (0111) in first and (1) in second.
I click 1st button (id:butt) and it calls number 111 (i typed 0111).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats logic: You parse the String "0111" to an Integer, but numbers never start with zero if it isnt zero itself or a float/double value. So Java removes the zero when parsing, because the zero is useless for a number, because it doesnt change the value of the number.

Comment: I live in Ukraine, so our phone numbers begin with zero. If we remove that zero, we will get a voice message "This is not allowed for your plan"

Comment: But you are starting the Intent with ("tel: " + telnum2) so you could simply not parse it to a Integer and say telnum2 is a String and the value equals exactly the String value of the TextView

Comment: Now it doesn't start call.

Comment: Oh, it is my fault. I enter wait time in milliseconds :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, you are parsing the number as an Integer

```
telnum2 = Integer.parseInt(telnum.getText().toString());
```

Leading Zeros in Numbers are stripped (0100 is the same number as 100 for example). You have to keep the number as String to preserve the leading zero.

Comment: Replacing int to string gives error : needs int, found java.lang.String

Answer (score 1):

Change the Variable type to String and Dont parse it to Integer.

Answer (score 1):

"Phone numbers" are not actually numbers, they are sequences of digits. They have no numeric magnitude ("my phone number is higher than yours!"), and in particular, leading zeros are significant, which is not the case for numbers. So you should always treat them as strings, not as numbers.